# NPM MSSQL - error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'release' of null

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, npm

I am trying to connect to the mssql server using [npm mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) module. I am getting below mentioned error, I tried to search about it and couldn't find anything helpful on it apart from few users already reported it on [GitHub](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql/issues/467) without any success.

```
error: uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'release' of null date=Sat Jul 15 2017 02:03:59 GMT+0000 (UTC), pid=10150, uid=1000, gid=1000, cwd=/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp, execPath=/usr/bin/nodejs, version=v6.11.1, argv=[/usr/bin/nodejs, /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js], rss=70537216, heapTotal=47235072, heapUsed=35834656, external=18214141, loadavg=[0.14794921875, 0.10498046875, 0.02880859375], uptime=2206463
TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of null
    at ConnectionPool.release (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/mssql/lib/base.js:199:14)
    at Request.tds.Request.err [as userCallback] (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:892:25)
    at Request._this.callback (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/tedious/lib/request.js:47:27)
    at Connection.message (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:1401:27)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:687:45)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:602:18)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/server/gcap-server-exp/node_modules/atpl-models/node_modules/tedious/lib/message-io.js:102:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
```

My code for creating a connection and executing the procedure is as follows -

```
sql.close()
sql.connect(sqlConfig).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
    .input('input', sql.NVarChar, input_value)
    .execute('someProcedure').then(result => {
      result.recordsets.forEach(record => {
        record.forEach(recordChild => {
         // Do something about the recordChild ...
        })
      })
    }, err => {
      // Log err
      console.log(err)
    }).catch(err => {
      // ... error checks 
      console.log(err)
    })
})
```

The `sqlConfig` parameter above is -

```
sqlConfig = {
  user: 'username',
  password: '******',
  server: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  database: 'database',
  pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this error is coming when you releasing mssql connection...

Comment: Yes it is right the error is while releasing the connection, however there is no mannual code to release the connection when you use mssql module it does the same by its own.

Comment: btw where are you releasing connection in your code..

Comment: No not at all. I am not releasing any connection in the code as you can see it in the question.

Comment: then what is this statement doing?? ```sql.close()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same issue, and here's what I had to do to avoid the error.

Here's my function that gets a connection to the database:

```
async function connectToDb() {
    const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(connectionConfig).connect();
    return pool;
}
```

Here's the function that does the query:

```
async function someDatabaseFunction(args, done) {
    let pool;
    let ps;

    try {
        pool = await connectToDb();
        ps = new sql.PreparedStatement(pool);
        ps.input('input1', sql.VarChar(10));

        const sqlStr = 'my query goes here';

        await ps.prepare(sqlStr);
        const result = await ps.execute({ groupId: args.groupId, status: args.status });

        done(null, result);
    } catch (error) {
        done(error);
    } finally {
        if (ps) await ps.unprepare();
        if (pool) pool.close();
    }
}
```

The issue for me was that in the finally block I was calling `ps.unprepare()` but didn't `await` that function. I was going right to the `pool.close()` function. `await`ing the `ps.unprepare` got rid of the error for me.

I'm not exactly sure if it applies to your situation, but it could, since you have a `sql.close()` being called right before `sql.connect`. It could be that you're calling `sql.close` on a null value and that's the resulting error.

Comment: Yes that is the way it should be, I lately figured it out, thanks for the answer.